# internal maven repo index won't update in m2eclipse

Tags: maven, repository, m2eclipse, nexus

I have a remote maven repo set up and can successfully upload artifacts and download via POMs. I also see the repo listed along with maven central in my m2eclipse global 'Maven Repositories'.

My problem is that while Maven Central is browsable and updatable in m2eclipse, my internal one is not and when it tries to update I get this:

"Unable to update index for Nexus|http://www.c3works.com:8081/nexus-webapp-1.9.1.1/content/groups/public"

Putting that url in a browser does work, though.

Any ideas how to make m2eclipse to index properly? Thanks!

Here is my .m2/settings.xml:

```
    <settings>
<mirrors> 
 <mirror>
    <id>Nexus</id> 
    <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name> 
    <url>http://www.c3works.com:8081/nexus-webapp-1.9.1.1/content/groups/public </url> 
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror> 
</mirrors>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it by launching the Nexus webapp and I choose repair index and rebuild index on the Public Repository Group.

I believe the issue had to deal with a non-existent index or a bad index.  Once the index exists then the m2eclipse plugin will be able to rebuild/update index in Maven Repository Eclipse view.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are behind a proxy server. If so, please configure eclipse and Nexus to use the proxy settings and try.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue, very annoying. The solution is as above, go to the Nexus web app and repair index and rebuild index. Then do a rebuild index within the Maven Repositories view in eclipse.